# Why does BinaryAccuracy() change its values?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I defined a jupyter python notebook with the following cells, that I execute one by one:

1st cell:

```
import tensorflow as tf

ba = tf.keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy()

labels = [ 
np.array([[0]], dtype=np.float32),
np.array([[0]], dtype=np.float32),
np.array([[1]], dtype=np.float32),
np.array([[1]], dtype=np.float32),
np.array([[0]], dtype=np.float32) 
]

preds = [ 
np.array([[0.1]], dtype=np.float32),
np.array([[0.1]], dtype=np.float32),
np.array([[0.9]], dtype=np.float32),
np.array([[0.1]], dtype=np.float32),
np.array([[0]], dtype=np.float32) 
]
```

2nd cell:

```
ba(labels, preds)
> <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.8>
```

3rd cell:

```
ba(np.ones(100), np.ones(100))
> <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.8333333>
```

Note how the result in the 3rd cell is just plain wrong! It should be `1.0`, since its a perfect match. And if I execute this cell *multiple times*, the value differs too!

However, if I leave out the 2nd cell and only execute the 1st and then 3rd cell, the calculation is right. This is strange behaviour.

Why does BinaryAccuracy() change its values? Is this a bug, am I doing something wrong, is my setup wrong, or is it just some mechanism that Im not aware of?

Also, if once you've executed only 1st and 3rd cell and then go back executing the 2nd cell *multiple times*, the value differs each time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use `reset_states()`

```
np.random.seed(33)

ba = tf.keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy()

print(ba(np.random.randint(0,3, (100)), np.random.randint(0,3, (100)))) # 0.3

ba.reset_states()

print(ba(np.ones(100), np.ones(100))) # 1.0
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @MarcoCerliani! Obviously its important to `reset_states()` in order to clear hidden states, but where and why does `BinaryAccuracy()` have these hidden states? Its not even part of a model, just a simple tf metric that is called..

Comment: BinaryAccuracy and other tf metrics have this behavior, this is useful when u used the metric inside a training process. U are using BinaryAccuracy simply as a stand-alone function but the behavior remains; so simply using reset_states, always before u used it, does the job... don't forget to upvote ;-)